# Bulid Autoware from source, ros dependencies error?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am tring to build autoware from source following https://github.com/Autoware-AI/autoware.ai/wiki/Source-Build, and when I execute

```
rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO
```

I get the following error about ros dependencies:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
lanelet2_extension: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [lanelet2_validation]
lanelet_aisan_converter: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [lanelet2_traffic_rules]
mpc_follower: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [qpoases_vendor]
```

os-ubuntu16.04
ros-kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361256/bulid-autoware-from-source,-ros-dependencies-error?/) by [zjt](https://answers.ros.org/users/59205/zjt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@zjt what version of Autoware are you trying to build?

---

Originally posted by [sgermanserrano](https://answers.ros.org/users/41059/sgermanserrano/) with karma: 166 on 2020-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zjt](https://answers.ros.org/users/59205/zjt/) on 2020-09-11**:
According this https://github.com/Autoware-AI/autoware.ai/wiki/Source-Build#supported-configurations link, I have tried 1.13 and 1.14, both same error occured.

**Comment by [sgermanserrano](https://answers.ros.org/users/41059/sgermanserrano/) on 2020-09-11**:
can you try 1.12? 1.13 and 1.14 are not compatible with ubuntu 16 as shown in the table